# disable folder virtualization in windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista

I currently have a c++ application that gets built on xp and windows vista/7 virtualize some of the paths which i dont want it to do.

Some [sites says](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/MakingAppsUACAware.aspx) to add this to manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

How ever that is for .net applications. How can i do this under c++ for visual studio 2005?

.

Edit: I needed to download the vista sdk and include its bin path in visual studio before this would work.

Comment: try boxedapp. it may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same. Create a file with the given context and add that file in your project settings:

- *Manifest Tool* > *Input and Output* > *Additional Manifest Files*

Done!

Comment: Thanks, i was trying that except i was adding it to the wrong build thus couldnt work out why it wasnt working.